# Problem virtualizing Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit on VirtualBox 3.1 on Windows Vista 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04

### Software & Hardware Setup

***Host System*** : *Windows Vista Home Premium SP1 64 bit*
***Guest*** : *Ubuntu 10.04 (ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso) 32 bit*
***VM*** : *VirtualBox 3.1.8*
***Hardware*** : *Intel Core 2 Duo T6400 4GB SDRAM*

---

### What Happened

I followed the tutorial called Installing Ubuntu inside Windows using VirtualBox located here:
***www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox***

At first I downloaded ***ubuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.iso*** because I figured that it would be a perfect fit with my Vista 64 OS. I was wrong because it turns out the my Intel Core 2 Duo T6400 CPU does not have Intel® Virtualization Technology. So I had to go with the ***ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso*** which is 32 bit. This got me to the point where I could actually create the Ubuntu VM.

So I set up the VM in VirtualBox (according to the tutorial I was following) to prepare for the Ubuntu 10.04 virtualization. *Please go to my Picassa web album to see the screen shots of my VM settings and Ubuntu boot process so you can see what I experienced (they appear in the order that I experienced them in).*

***www.picasaweb.google.com/rubysiddhi/ProblemVirtualizingUbuntu100432BitOnVirtualBox31OnWindowsVista64#***

The first 17 images show the VM settings. The last 8 show my attempt at virtualizing Ubuntu 10.04. You can see booting up but ultimately failing.

### The Specifics

The one error message I got was:

> (process:210): GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id (0)

It appeared on a black screen that sort of looked like a Windows console screen but with out the c:\ or the ability to type. Then this error message got more complex when tons of text appeared in the screen. Pictures 23 - 25 in the album show this text.

I should also mention that I found this post in the Ubuntu forums by ***zonination*** who seemed to have similar problems to mine even though they had a different set up. The main issue I think ***zonination*** and me may be having is the fact that we can not change the color mode to **32 bit** while it is booting. I think the **16 bit** color mode maybe making Ubuntu fail. Not certain though.

Well I hope I explained my problem thoroughly and clearly. Thanks for the tutorial. It got me started but, now I hope to finish this process so I can start developing in Ubuntu.

OH by the way if you want to actually see what happened play by play (with some classical in the background) check out the video I made over here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMbbm5E_0Xw

Thanks!

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are new to virtualization and Linux, and as such would suggest that you try a different operating system and see if that works rather than spend time and effort on a problem that you may or may not be able to solve easily.

I would try a smaller distribution such as [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), to make sure that the host and Virtualbox are working correctly without having a large download. Don't bother to try and install (unless you want to, of course...), just see if it boots properly.

For a "real" Linux I'd go for one of OpenSuse, Fedora or Debian, in that order, but there are a stupid number of others.

Comment: i have no idea how to install that Damn Small Linux. There is no single .iso . I'm lost.

Comment: Download an iso, the basic one, [dsl-4.4.10.iso](http://ftp.belnet.be/packages/damnsmalllinux/current/dsl-4.4.10.iso) should be fine. Add it to the Media Manager, as you did with the UBuntu CD. Create a new machine, accepting all the defaults, don't worry about it being a "windows machine" at the moment. On "storage", add the DSL CD and then start the machine.